# API to query current VS Code word wrap setting

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The VS Code `wordWrap` setting can be toggled via the command 
`editor.action.toggleWordWrap`.

But is there an extension API available to query the current state (`off|on|wordWrapColumn|bounded`)?

Is there an event available which is fired, if the setting is changed? Something like `vscode.window.onDidChangeXxx`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to react to changes to the configuration, you can use code like this:

```
workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration(() => {
    let config = workspace.getConfiguration('editor');
    let wordWrap = config.get('wordwrap', false);
});
```

If you just want to get the wordwrap setting at some point in time, you can use the inner calls shown to get the configuration and the specific setting.

The details about the workspace configuration are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-nameworkspaceconfigurationaspan-classcodeitem-id855workspaceconfigurationspan).

Edit: regarding the toggleWordWrap command, no there is no way to react to that change, only to manual settings changes. This is due to them moving the toggle word wrap setting into memory as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20675#issuecomment-282691380). If you would like to request that as a feature, open an [issue on github](https://www.github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)

Comment: The snippet above works to detect changes made in the settings file, but does not work to detect word wrap changes invoked by `editor.action.toggleWordWrap` (default keybinding `Alt+z`)

Comment: You are correct, this changed in 1.10 and I didn't realize it. Details are in this comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20675#issuecomment-282691380

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace) event